# How can I translate "Unit Manufacturing Processes" to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I guess it's "proceso de fabricación por unidad", but I don't know if this it's correct.

I want to translate the paper's title this is what I guess: "Una representación del conocimiento para el proceso de fabricación por unidad"
([Source](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00170-014-5864-x#page-1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title you want to translate is:

> A knowledge representation for unit manufacturing processes

**Manufacturing** can be translated as:

- fabricación
- producción
- manufactura (the supposedly more direct translation)

Then, **unit processes** would sound good as:

- procesos unitarios
- en/por unidades

So all together I would say:

> Representación del conocimiento de los procesos de fabricación por
>   unidades.

Comment: `[...]de frabricación de unidades` is maybe better no?

Comment: @Joze that could be a good addition. However, I miss context to know what is best: "por unidades" emphasizes the fact that it is done one by one, whereas "de unidades" emphasizes the production itself.

Comment: Yes exactly. We would need more details indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the paper i found that the correct translation would be something like: "Representación del conocimiento de los procesos de producción unitarios" or "Representación del conocimiento de los procesos unitarios de producción"

From the paper:

> The manufacturing process of a mechanical product usually consists
>   of a series of sequenced individual operations. Each operation is
>   known as a unit manufacturing process, such as casting, turning, and
>   surface treatment. For brevity, in this paper they are referred to as
>   unit processes.